# Как сделать чтоб не сильно шумел кулер в Debian 9

Tags: linux, debian

Установил Linux на ноутбук, теперь кулер постоянно шумит и довольно сильно.
вывод sensors:

```
asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:     4100 RPM
temp1:        +65.0°C  

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +65.0°C  (crit = +103.0°C)

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
GPU core:     +0.85 V  (min =  +0.85 V, max =  +1.03 V)
temp1:        +65.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +65.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +64.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +63.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

Comment: Чистил давно и термопасту менял?

Comment: я первое что делаю в таких ноутах, сношу эту глючную гадость - nouveau и ставлю видеодрайвер от nvidia

Comment: у меня почемута дрова не встаю((((